# Collection using Generics typecasting problem for Implementation and Interface

Tags: java, generics, interface

Given:

```
interface ViewableDTO {//methods here}

class PersonDTO implements ViewableDTO {//implementation here}
```

This works fine:

```
PersonDTO p = new PersonDTO();
ViewableDTO v = p; //works
```

How come this doesn't work:

```
List<PersonDTO> plist = getPersonDtoList();
List<ViewableDTO> vlist = plist; //compilation error
List<ViewableDTO> vlist = (List<ViewableDTO>)plist; //compilation error
```

My solution here is to do this:

```
List<ViewableDTO> vlist = new ArrayList<ViewableDTO>();
vlist.addAll(plist);
```

My question is, is this the only / best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider what you can do with a `List<ViewableDTO>`. You can add *any* object of a type implementing `ViewableDTO`. Do you really want this to compile?

```
List<PersonDTO> plist = getPersonDtoList();
List<ViewableDTO> vlist = plist;
vlist.add(new OtherDTO());
```

?

No - it's only safe to get things *out* of the list in that form, so you use something like this:

```
List<PersonDTO> plist = getPersonDtoList();
List<? extends ViewableDTO> vlist = plist;
```

See the [Java Generics FAQ section on Wildcard Instantiations](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#WIldcard%20Instantiations) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
List<? extends ViewableDTO> vlist = plist;
```

Please take a look at [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)